# Exterior product in relative cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, products

Let us consider two pair of spaces $(X, A)$ and $(Y, B)$. We set $(X, A) \wedge (Y, B) := (X \times Y, (X \times B) \cup (A \times Y))$. Given a cohomology theory $h^{\bullet}$, we can define a product $h^{\bullet}(X, A) \times h^{\bullet}(Y, B) \rightarrow h^{\bullet}((X, A) \wedge (Y, B))$. In the case of singular cohomology, this can be done via a suitable construction using cochains. In general, if $(X, A)$ and $(Y, B)$ are CW-pairs, we have that $h^{\bullet}(X, A) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(X/A)$, $h^{\bullet}(Y, B) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(Y/B)$ and $h^{\bullet}((X, A) \wedge (Y, B)) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(X \times Y /(X \times B) \cup (A \times Y)) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(X/A \wedge Y/B)$, hence we easily get the product.

Let us consider the relative cones $C(X, A)$ and $C(Y, B)$. We have that $h^{\bullet}(X, A) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(C(X, A))$ and $h^{\bullet}(Y, B) \simeq \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(C(Y, B))$. We get a natural product with value in $C(X, A) \wedge C(Y, B)$, but the exterior product, previously defined, takes value in $C((X, A) \wedge (Y, B)) = (C(X \times Y, (X \times B) \cup (A \times Y))$.

We do not manage to find a natural map from $C((X, A) \wedge (Y, B))$ to $C(X, A) \wedge C(Y, B)$, in order to define the product via the pull-back. If $(X, A)$ and $(Y, B)$ are CW-pairs, then $C(X, A)$ has the same homotopy type of $C(X, A)/CA \simeq X/A$, and the same holds for the other pairs, hence $C((X, A) \wedge (Y, B))$ and $C(X, A) \wedge C(Y, B)$ have the same homotopy type. Does this hold for generic pairs? If the answer is negative, is there a natural way to define the product via the cones?

The motivation of the question is the following. We want to define the relative product for two generic maps $\rho: A \rightarrow X$ and $\eta: B \rightarrow Y$, not necessarily embeddings. We have that $h^{\bullet}(\rho) := \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(C(\rho))$ and $h^{\bullet}(\eta) := \tilde{h}^{\bullet}(C(\eta))$, hence we get a product with value in $\tilde{h}^{\bullet}(C(\rho) \wedge C(\eta))$. We define the map $\rho \wedge \eta: (X \times B) \cup_{A \times B} (A \times Y) \rightarrow X \times Y$ by $(x, b) \mapsto (x, \eta(b))$ and $(a, y) \mapsto (\rho(a),y)$, and we need to define a product with values in $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$. The question is: do $C(\rho) \wedge C(\eta)$ and $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$ have the same homotopy type? If not, how can we define the product?

Comment: What is the domain of $\rho\wedge\eta$? Is it simply the pushout of $X\times B\leftarrow X\times Y\rightarrow A\times Y$? If so, then it is not what you want in general.

Comment: Tom: there are no maps  $X\times Y \to X \times B$, $X\times Y \to A\times Y$. I think the $X\times Y$ should be $A\times B$.

Comment: The domain is $(X \times B) \sqcup_{X \times Y} (A \times Y)$, I corrected the text of the question. This means that $(x, b) \sim (a, y)$ if and only if $(x, \eta(b)) = (\rho(a), y)$. When $\rho$ and $\eta$ are embeddings, it coincides with $(X \times B) \cup (A \times Y)$.

Comment: @Fabio : I was confused by your notation, which doesn't seem to be standard. I guess the standard way to write it is this: let $P$ be the *pullback* of the maps $X\times B \to X \times Y$ and $A\times Y \to X\times Y$. Then your space is the *pushout* of the diagram $X\times B \leftarrow P \to A\times Y$. Right?

Comment: I think the domain of $\rho \wedge \eta$ is the push-out of $A \times Y \leftarrow A \times B \rightarrow X \times B$. We consider the disjoint union $(A \times Y) \sqcup (X \times B)$ and identify $(\rho(a), b) \sim (a, \eta(b))$. The map $\rho \wedge \eta$, with codomain $X \times Y$, is $(a, y) \mapsto (\rho(a), y)$ and $(x, b) \mapsto (x, \eta(b))$. I would like to show that $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$ has the same homotopy type of $C(\rho) \wedge C(\eta)$.

Comment: @Fabio If what you are saying is correct then you are using incorrect notation: it is more correct to write $A \times Y \cup_{A \times B} X\times B$, even though $A\times B$ isn't a subset of either $A\times Y$ or $X\times B$. I doubt that $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$ has the correct homotopy type unless you assume that $A \to X$ and $B\to Y$ are cofibrations.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the text of the question, thank you. Actually I have no reason to think that they have the same homotopy type, I just hope it. If not, I would like to find any way to pass from the cohomology of $C(\rho) \wedge C(\eta)$ to the one of $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$. Now I am trying to see if prop. 9.8 pag. 224 of the book of Strom, "Modern classical homotopy theory", can help.

Comment: What do you mean by the "relative cone" $C(X,A)$? Is it the mapping cone of the inclusion $X\cup CA$? Also the $\wedge$ notation is confusing. Do you mean the smash product when you say $C(\rho)\wedge C(\eta)$? If so, how are these spaces pointed?

Comment: The relative cone is the mapping cone of the inclusion. In every cone the marked point is the vertex, hence there is a natural marked point in order to define the smashed product.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you take $\rho=\eta$ to be the constant map from $S^1$ to the one point space, then $C(\rho)\wedge C(\eta)$ is $S^4$. If I understand your definition of $C(\rho\wedge \eta)$ then in this example, that space is an interval (the mapping cone of the map from a one point space to a one point space). However, if you switch your definition of $\rho \wedge \eta$ to have domain the homotopy pushout (or double mapping cylinder), then you do get that $C(\rho \wedge \eta)$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^4$.

Comment: I think that if you redefine $\rho \wedge \eta$ to be the natural map from the homotopy pushout of $X \times B \leftarrow A\times B \rightarrow A \times Y$ to $X \times Y$, then $C(\rho\wedge \eta)$ and $C(\rho) \wedge C(\eta)$ are actually homeomorphic. Write both spaces as quotients of $X \times Y \coprod A \times [0,1] \times Y \coprod X \times B \times [0,1] \coprod A \times B \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually the homotopy push-out is well-behaved with respect to homotopy equivalence, hence it seems to be more suitable to define the product in cohomology. When $\rho$ and $\eta$ are embeddings, the homotopy push-out of $X \times B \leftarrow A \times B \rightarrow A \times Y$ has the same homotopy type of the ordinary push-out (you can shrink the cylinder), hence it should be the correct generalization. I will check if everything works for the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: No problem. If you just want homotopy equivalence, you can also reduce to the initial situation of embeddings by replacing $X$ with the mapping cylinder of $\rho$ and $Y$ with the mapping cylinder of $\eta$. Then $X\times Y$ will be replaced by a homotopy equivalent space but this will not matter as the mapping cone is homotopy invariant.